# nodejs | async main thread takes a few seconds to finish

Tags: node.js, async-await, pg-promise

I have a small nodejs script that run an async query to a db using `pg-promise` but for some reason the script **hangs a few seconds before finishing** (ie, before I get back access to the terminal). **Why is that happening?** This is not really a big isssue but I don't understand why the main thread hangs a few seconds.

The code is:

```js
import pgpPackage from 'pg-promise';
const pgp = pgpPackage();

const env = {
  dbUrl: process.env.DB_URL
};

const app = {
  db: pgp(env.dbUrl),
};

const main = async () => {
  console.log(await app.db.any('select 1'));
  return 42;
};

try {
  const x = await main();
  console.log('all ok, main returned', x);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('an error occurred:', err);
};
```

What I get is:

```sh
>> DB_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres1234@localhost:5432/panaderias node index.js
[ { '?column?': 1 } ]
all ok, main returned 42
 <--- At this point it hangs for ~10 seconds and then it finishes without issues
```

For reference,

```sh
>> node --version
v16.1.0
```

The db is running in a docker container but that should not be relevant.

---

If I replace

```js
  console.log(await app.db.any('select 1'));
```

with

```js
  console.log(await 1);
```

then the scripts ends immediately.

---

The question is why the script takes a few seconds to finish. My guess is that some promise is left hanging but I can not figure out what's happening.

Comment: I would guess that the database is using some timer that keeps the nodejs process running until the timer stops.  Perhaps if you explicitly close down the database that wouldn't happen or configure the database to use shorter timers.

Comment: yep, that was it, added `  app.db.$pool.end();` and how it ends correctly

Comment: I have added an update section to my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library `pg-promise` is based on the use of a connection pool, which cashes live connections, to provide fast responsiveness.

The pool's default configuration lets live connections hang idle for 30 seconds (configurable), before they are released.

When writing a pass-through app one usually adds manual pool termination, to force immediate release of all connections, and exit from the process...

**release one specific pool:**

```js
db.$pool.end();
```

**release all pools in the process:**

```js
pgp.end();
```

[It is documented in the library](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#library-de-initialization), and [shown in the examples](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/tree/master/examples).

#### UPDATE

From pg-promise `v10.11.0`, you no longer need to shut down the pool explicitely. Instead, you can just set connection option `allowExitOnIdle: true`, to let process exit when pool is idle.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the database is using some timer that keeps the nodejs process running until the timer stops. Perhaps if you explicitly close down the database or the connection pool that wouldn't happen.  Or, you can configure the database to use shorter timers.

And, as you have reported:

```
app.db.$pool.end();
```

will stop the delay.

Comment: This is no longer necessary, see the update section in my answer.